# Best way to assign default entity values in NestJS

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I am new to NestJS and prefer to always work with Typescript's `"strict": true` compiler option. However when I do this a few of the auto-generated files throw errors due to no default values being set.  For example I have this Entity file

`organization.entity.ts`

```ts
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { OrganizationTypeEnum } from './organization-type.enum';

@Entity({ name: 'Organization' })
export class OrganizationEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column({ default: null })
  logoUrl: string | null;

  @Column({ default: OrganizationTypeEnum.COBRAND })
  type: OrganizationTypeEnum;
}
```

Which gives an error like this for each property

```txt
Property id has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
```

What is the proper convention here?  Should I:

- assign a value directly like `id: string = '';`
- give it a non-null assertion like `id!: string;`

Or is there something else I should do instead? Assigning a value feels wrong because I don't think that value would ever be used anywhere and it's potentially misleading. Perhaps strigc mode in typescript isn't worth it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution would be to set the tsconfig option `strictPropertyInitialization` to false, for the sake of both your DTOs and your entities

Comment: Thanks, I suppose this probably is the easiest way to do this for a NestJS project. I prefer strict types but if this is gonna be common in Nest I don't see a reason to add non-null assertions all over the place.